# What's the Linux command equivalent for "msg.exe"?

Tags: linux, networking, instant-messaging

I'm trying to send a message from my Linux box to a windows 7 box, à la "net send".

I've tried

```
smbclient -M machine
```

but that gives

```
Connection to machine failed. Error NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
```

From what I've read, "net send" no longer exists and on a Windows box, and you would use "msg.exe".  How do I send a message from Linux to the Windows 7 box, though?

Comment: Do you want one way communication like `wall` or two way like `talk`? Would setting up a personal IRC server work for this situation?

Comment: One way is fine.  Something like a personal IRC server would be a possibility, but I'm trying to find a method that works like "net send" used to - popping up a message on the screen.  I could, of course, write up something, but I'd prefer to use something that already exists.

Comment: Hmm... Further searching returns this [ServerFault thread](http://serverfault.com/questions/137135/what-does-nt-status-bad-network-name-mean-in-samba) which goes over the error you posted. Check that and see if you can get Samba to work.